# Spring boot-Ckeditor upload image and get image url on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, ckeditor4.x

Integrating CKEditor 4 on jsp with Springboot to get WYSIWYG for blog content but,
I am trying to upload image on ckeditor and get url of image.
Images uploads but dont get response to image info

jsp file

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<form class="editorform row" method="post" action="/image/upload">
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn btn-outline-success">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <textarea name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>

    </div>

</form>

<Script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/image/upload',
        height: 400
    });
</Script>
```

created a apicontroller to upload and get url of image

apicontroller.java

```java
package com.digimartnepal.digimartnepal.controller;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class ApiController {

@PostMapping("/image/upload")
    @SneakyThrows
    public String upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile upload, HttpServletRequest request){
    String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    File files = new File(path + "upload");
    files.mkdir();
    upload.transferTo(new File(files.getPath()+File.separator+upload.getOriginalFilename()));
    System.out.println(upload.getOriginalFilename());
    return request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+"/upload/"+upload.getOriginalFilename();
}
}
```